# cannot save after the first 5000 sec

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need the textarea auto save every 5 second, but somehow it just save at the first 5 second and will not save after that. can someone help????

index.php

```
<div class="container"> 
<div class="form-group">  
                 <textarea name="iti" style="border-style:none" id="iti" rows="3" class="form-control"><?php echo $res['iti'];?></textarea>  
            </div>
<div class="form-group">  
                 <input type="hidden" name="gp_name" id="gp_name" value="<?php echo $res['gp_name'];?>" />
                 <div id="autoSave"></div>  
            </div>  
       </div>

<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){
var timer;
var timeout = 1000;
$('#iti').change(function(){

if(timer) {
clearTimeout(timer);
}
timer = setTimeout(autoSave, timeout); 

});
});

function autoSave(){
       var iti = $('#iti').val();
       var gp_name = $('#gp_name').val();
if(iti != '')  
{  
        $.ajax({  
             url:"lotus_iti_save.php",  
             method:"POST",  
                 data:{iti:iti, gp_name:gp_name},  
             dataType:"text",  
             success:function(data)  
            {  
                  if(data != '')  
                  {  
                       $('#gp_name').val(data);
                  }  
                  $('#autoSave').text(location.reload());  

            }  
    });  
} 
}   
</script>

<div class="container"> 
<div class="form-group">  
                 <textarea name="iti" style="border-style:none" id="iti2" rows="3" class="form-control"><?php echo $res['iti2'];?></textarea>  
            </div>
<div class="form-group">  
                 <input type="hidden" name="gp_name" id="gp_name" value="<?php echo $res['gp_name'];?>" />
                 <div id="autoSave2"></div>  
            </div>  
       </div>

<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){
var timer2;
var timeout2 = 1000;
$('#iti2').change(function(){

if(timer2) {
clearTimeout(timer2);
}
timer2 = setTimeout(autoSave2, timeout2); 

});
});

function autoSave2(){
       var iti = $('#iti2').val();
       var gp_name = $('#gp_name').val();
if(iti != '')  
{  
        $.ajax({  
             url:"lotus_iti_save.php",  
             method:"POST",  
                 data:{iti:iti, gp_name:gp_name},  
             dataType:"text",  
             success:function(data)  
            {  
                  if(data != '')  
                  {  
                       $('#gp_name').val(data);
                  }  
                  $('#autoSave2').text(location.reload());  

            }  
    });  
} 
}   
</script>
```

autosave.php

```
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
 if(isset($_POST["iti"]) )
 {
 $post_iti = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["iti"]);
 if($_POST["gp_name"] != '')  
 {  
 //update post  
 $sql = "UPDATE info SET iti = '".$post_iti."' WHERE gp_name = '".$_POST["gp_name"]."'";  
 mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
 }  
 }
```

I have try to find solution on the internet, but unfortunately that I cannot find it at the moment, someone could help me out????

I have update my code, there are two textarea, the js code seems cannot share with the other textarea, so I create the other one， it is working fine for the first one and the rest are not working.

I have try to delete the first one, then the second one is working

Comment: Please see updated answer

Comment: thanks, I have encounter the other problem, I need the code share with multiple table, but when I create the other table, only the first table will update the data, the rest of them has on result. do you guys know why and how to deal with this situation?

Comment: Sorry did not get exactly what you need. you mean you need to send data to multiple tables but for the first table it is working fine but not for the other ?

Comment: sorry for making you confused. my question is if the page have two or more tables need to use the same js code to send data to database, then only the first table is working fine.

Comment: try check the event and field if they are same then it will work automatically

Comment: no, it seems doesn't work if i create another textarea in the same page. it should use class instead of id, but I don't know how to write the code correctly...

Comment: Could you please add what you have written and tried ?

Comment: I have update the code, please check it

Comment: Try make the Id of gp_name different in each like like iti id

Comment: yes, both textarea are working, thanks!!! do you know how to rewrite the code if I use class instead of id? I am an old man want to learn new thing...

Comment: Great could you please mark my answer as accepted and an upvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to be fine just try returning some response from the autosave.php file so that your data can be put into the hidden input.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){  
 function autoSave()  
 {  
   var iti = $('#iti').val();
   var gp_name = $('#gp_name').val();
   if(iti != '')  
   {  
        $.ajax({  
             url:"test2.php",  
             method:"POST",  
             data:{iti:iti, gp_name:gp_name},  
             dataType:"text",  
             success:function(data)  
             {      

                  if(data != '')  
                  {  
                       $('#gp_name').val($.trim(data));
                  }  
                  $('#autoSave').text("Post save as draft");  
                  setInterval(function(){  
                       $('#autoSave').text('');  
                  }, 5000);  
             }  
        });  
   }            
 }  
  setInterval(function(){   
      autoSave();   
     }, 5000);  
 });

 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
 if(isset($_POST["iti"]) )
 {
   $post_iti = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["iti"]);
   if($_POST["gp_name"] != '')  
   {  
    //update post  
     $sql = "UPDATE info SET iti = '".$post_iti."' WHERE gp_name = '".$_POST["gp_name"]."'";  
   mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
   echo $_POST['gp_name'];die;
  }  
 }
```

Also try different time between show hide and request send. so change this time to

```
setInterval(function(){  
     $('#autoSave').text('');  
}, 3000);
```

So that you can see success message.

**Warning**: You are wide open to SQL Injections and should use parameterized prepared statements instead of manually building your queries.

Comment: try using console log if you are getting any jquery error because code is fine

Comment: Could you please update your code as I did. I have tested it and it is working on my end. Please update and mark this as answer and with upvote.

Comment: you gp_name got updated it there is no data. there seems to be some issue with the line if data != ''

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var timer;
 var timeout = 5000;
 $('#postTitle,#postContent').keyup(function(){

  if(timer) {
   clearTimeout(timer);
  }
  timer = setTimeout(autoSave, timeout); 

 });
});

function autoSave(){
    var postid = $('#postid').val();
    var title = $('#postTitle').val().trim();
    var content = $('#postContent').val().trim();
    var iti = $('#iti').val();
       var gp_name = $('#gp_name').val();
       if(iti != '')  
       {  
            $.ajax({  
                 url:"autosave.php",  
                 method:"POST",  
                 data:{iti:iti, gp_name:gp_name},  
                 dataType:"text",  
                 success:function(data)  
                {  
                      if(data != '')  
                      {  
                           $('#gp_name').val(data);
                      }  
                      $('#autoSave').text("Post save as draft");  

                }  
        });  
    } 
}
```

Try this code and move the function out of ready function.

Comment: Did you try it in different browser?

Comment: yes, I have try on microsoft edge, chrome and get same result, I have to refresh the browser every time and it will work once

Comment: Remove the  $('#postTitle,#postContent').keyup(function(){ } and write  timer = setTimeout(autoSave, timeout); directly with in ready function.